# MYSQL Get items where current dayofweek is in list

Tags: mysql, list, dayofweek

I want to get certain records that meet certain criteria. One of them is that they can only be found if the current day of the week is found in a certain column. I have the query below, and it works if I just input the weekdays myself, but doesn't return any results if i use a fieldname..

So the field 'dagen' contains either * for any day, of a list of weekdays like '5','6' for Thursday and Friday.

```
SELECT * FROM playlist_item 
WHERE playlist_id='31' 
AND type_id='56' 
AND jobcomplete='0' 
AND startuur<=TIME(NOW()) AND einduur >=TIME(NOW()) 
AND (dagen='*' OR DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) IN (dagen));
```

If I replace dagen at the end with .. IN (5,6) it works perfectly, but not when using a column name.. I've tried it without single quotes as a value, with quotes.. None of them work.. What is the correct way to get the result I want?

SQLFiddle exaple can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c6ce/1)

Comment: can you provide the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example of your problem with the sample dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that dagen is a column that contains a comma separated list of days of the week, try something like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM playlist_item 
WHERE playlist_id='31' 
AND type_id='56' 
AND jobcomplete='0' 
AND startuur<=TIME(NOW()) AND einduur >=TIME(NOW()) 
AND (dagen='*' OR FIND_IN_SET(DAYOFWEEK(NOW()), dagen));
```

Note that a comma separated list is generally a sign of a poorly normalised database.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I'm always looking to improve, how would you select the days on which that record should be found?

Comment: I would suggest a better solution would be to set up another table with one row per day of the week and playlist. Then you can do a simple join which will be indexed and likely substantially quicker than using FIND_IN_SET (which can't use indexes).